# I'm trying to create a form in access 2007 with 2 drop down boxes to view a report by state or name

Tags: ms-access

im an intern at a database mngmt company and the boss is training me in access...i took the access tutorials and were definitely not enough info involved to do a what seems a simple task.my problem is this:

i have a simple table with contact info with 16 colums (`Local_Utility, Requested_User_Type, First_Name, Last_Name, Address 1, Address 2, Country, State, City, Zip, Phone_Number, Username\Email, Password, Confirm Password, and Parcel_Number`), with 6 rows of names (keep in mind this is just a test to help me from the boss)

I created a form and with 2 drop down boxes (Last Name and State) and im trying to create a view button to view an individual report for a query i made for just simple contact info with 6 colums (`Last_Name, First_Name, Address1, City, State, and Phone_Number`)

Problem1 is that i can view the query with the view by name or state button but cant view a simple individual report from the query using the button

Problem2 is that for criteria on the query i put `Forms!frmMyparamForm!txtMyStateParamField`
for the state drop box it works, but when i use `Forms!frmMyparamForm!txtMyNameParamField` it doesnt and that annoying parameter box pops up

Problem3 is that after i close the query, all the states and names in my dropdown box on the form disappear

Im a beginner at this please help me

Answer (score 0):

If a parameter box is popping up, by far the most likely problem is that you have misspelled the name. If the param box asks for txtMyNameParamField, then double check that that is what you called the control and that the form is open.

If states and names are disappearing, you will need to post some code. Thses things do not happen automatically.